# Jasmine: Mocking inner method of singleton

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6

How would I **mock** the call to a method of a singleton, like:

```
Foo.get().getBar();
```

It seems straightforward to mock `Foo.getBar();` with

```
jasmine.createSpyObj(Foo, ['get']);
Foo.get.and.returnValue();
```

But I've been noodling with dependency injection and can't quite get it to work just right. FWIW: `getBar` returns a promise, so I'm really trying to mock `Foo.get().getBar().then()` which I imagine must be something like

```
Foo.get.getBar.and.callFake(() => { return deferred.promise; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
describe('Foo.get().getBar()',function(){
  it('is happy',function(){
    var Foo = jasmine.createSpyObj('Foo', ['get']);
    console.log(Foo);
    Foo.get.andReturn({
      getBar: function() {
        return 'happy';
      }
    });
    expect(Foo.get().getBar()).toBe('happy');
  });
});
```

Hope that helps!!!